# Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Reducer :**

```
function listPeopleByName (state = {
    getPeopleName:{}
}, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case C.LIST_PEOPLE_NAME:{        
            return {
                ...state
                ,getPeopleName :action.payload
            }
        }
        default : {}
    }
    return state
}
```

**Action:**

```
function listPeopleByName(config) {

  return function (dispatch) {
    ApiService(config)
      .then((resp) => {
        dispatch({
          type: C.LIST_PEOPLE_NAME,
          payload: resp.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch({
          type: C.LIST_PEOPLE_NAME,
          payload: error,
        });
      });
  };
}
```

**ApiService** is a function that make an axios request and returns a respones

**Dispatching code :**

```
  listPeopleByNameFunction = () => {
    const listPeopleByNameParam = {
        id: someone,      
      },
    let data = {
      PeopleId: "snjenfner",
    };
    let listPeopleByNameCategory = getApiConfig(
      "POST",
      listPeopleByNameParam,
      data
    );
    this.props.listPeopleByName(listPeopleByNameCategory);
  };

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  listPeopleByName: (config) => dispatch(listPeopleByName(config)),

});
```

Although I take the previous state (...state) and change the state with the payload i'm getting, it still shows the state is mutated. I would have used reduxtoolkit but this is a way old project that doesn't need to be migrated to reduxtoolkit.

Comment: Unrelated but return state from default close.

Comment: I'm also struggling to reconcile what your `listPeopleByName` function is doing and how it's wrapped by a call to `dispatch`... it doesn't appear to be an action creator, it doesn't return an action object nor a Promise. Are you naming ***two*** functions the same name? As in, `listPeopleByName` in your snippet is a callback function in a component, that ultimately calls `listPeopleByName` action?

Comment: I'm calling the action from dispatch (class component way). I have edited the code.
The function `listPeopleByNameFunction` actually makes sends the api config to my action, in which there the api is called. I have added the action to the edit

Comment: I see. And what is the state mutation? My guess is that you've mapped some state to props, and in a component unintentionally applied a mutation. Does the error say or show what was mutated between state updates?

Comment: Yes, The error log : `Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'listPeopleByName.getPeopleName.data.0'.  This may cause incorrect behavior.`

Comment: Yeah, I think something has mutated the nested `data` property. Is `data` an array? Can you share this `listPeopleByName.getPeopleName` state value? Can you find and include any component code that touches/consumes this part of your state?